# GCP data Loss Prevention - not detecting local types

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-loss

I am working with GCP's DLP APi, and I have issues detecting country-specific types. On the other hand, I have no issues with global types ([here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference) you can find the list of types). Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this? In case it might help, I'm working from outside the US.

This is a copy of my config file:

```
info_types_rep_names = {"PHONE_NUMBER": "[PHONE]",
                        "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "[EMAIL]",
                        "US_PASSPORT": "[PASSPORT]",}

info_types = [{"name": key} for key, value in info_types_rep_names.items()]

deidentify_config = {
    "info_type_transformations": {
        "transformations": [ 
            {
                "info_types" : [{"name": key}],
                "primitive_transformation": {
                    "replace_config": {
                        "new_value": {"string_value": value}
                    }
                }
            } for key, value in info_types_rep_names.items()
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try verifying the likelihood value to match the infotype by following the [Likelihood](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/demo/#!/)

Comment: I'm already using the VERY_UNLIKELY setting... So I guess that the issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations might be affected in some scenarios. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/locations?_ga=2.117808909.-541253340.1636636756%20f) for Country specific values.

There is a piece of code and I could see that  there might be a chance that the provided value may be wrong.
I  have tested from our end with sample code using Python refer [document](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#dlp_deidentify_replace-python)  and for using info_types_rep_names, by changing the project id “input_str = 'Please call me. My phone number is. My email, just in case, is adfsfasfs@gmail.com. Take a note of US passport number: C03005988. Or maybe C03004786'” and works for US_PASSPORT, but the sample number should absolutely work for sure to be valid. Also there may be a possibility that only a country specific one may fail. But when tested with some other country specific value and it worked. Also I could see all the results are aligned with the demo detection.

Also making sure the right InfoTypes are in use on the right section.follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/demo/#!/) , and in the options tab you can view and adjust the InfoTypes.

So my first question is , is it getting aligned with correct Infotypes or not?

If it is aligned, then it is either our detection fails with specific samples or might be  the sample is not valid.

If it is not valid then it is either the matter of having the wrong sample or a bug in the code.
Please check and revert if there are any issues.